# What is the difference between the nuget packages hangfire.aspnetcore and hangfire and hangfire.core?

Tags: c#, nuget, asp.net-core-mvc, hangfire

What is the difference between the `nuget` packages [HangFire.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire.AspNetCore/) and [HangFire](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire/) and [HangFire.core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HangFire.Core/)?

It seems I am able to use hangfire with a ASP .NET MVC Core project with only the `HangFire` 1.6.21 package alone. See below packages used in my project:

[image]

What is then the package `HangFire.AspNetCore` for?

I am working with Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu, and I added the packages using :

```
dotnet add package Hangfire

dotnet add package Hangfire.AspNetCore
```

Comment: Links added, thanks for the head up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the usual naming convention for NuGet packages:

- **HangFire** is the package name and the main package which includes all dependencies needed. This main package targets .NET framework in this case.
- **HangFire.Core** is package that includes the core components, to which all variants of the package will probably be dependent on.
- **HangFire.AspNetCore** is extension to support .NET Core

Comment: Thanks. Any idea how come I can use hangfire jobs with .NET Core without **HangFire.AspNetCore**?

Comment: It's not possible. Why wouldn't you use AspNetCore package?

Comment: As far as I can tell, I am able to schedule and run background jobs using hangfire 1.6.21 without **HangFire.AspNetCore** on my ASP Core project on Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu. This is why I am asking what are the specificities of this package? Maybe it is an obsolete one?

Comment: It was automatically downloaded, check your packages.

Comment: That is correct, thanks. Based on [nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Hangfire/), the **Hangfire** package's dependencies include Hangfire.AspNetCore (= 1.6.21) and Hangfire.Core (= 1.6.21) and Hangfire.SqlServer (= 1.6.21)